# Pascal неправильно анализирует текстовый файл

Tags: pascal

Дан текстовый файл F. Определить количество пустых строк и напечатать их номера.
Когда определяем номер пустой строки - ошибка. К примеру пустая строка 2, а пишет 1.Изменение начального значения J вызывает ошибку в случае с пустой 1-ой строкой.
В чем ошибка?

```
uses crt;
var f:text;
    s:string;
    i,j,k,l:integer;
begin
clrscr;
{формируем файл}
assign(f,'1.txt'); {связь переменной с файлом}
reset(f);
i:=0;
j:=1;
Write('Пустые строки: ');
while not eof(f) do    {пока не конец файла}
begin
readln(f,s);
if eoln(f) then begin i:=i+1;
Write(j,',');
end;
j:=j+1;
end;
close(f);
writeln('Количество пустых строк:',i);
readln;
end.
```

Comment: > Pascal неправильно анализирует текстовый файл

Не надо обвинять в этом Pascal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока я поправлял и тестировал, [@teano](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5098/teano) уже сказал, что сделать надо. Вот код:

```
uses crt;
var 
  f:text;
  s:string;
  i,j:integer;
begin
  clrscr;
  {формируем файл}
  assign(f,'1.txt'); {связь переменной с файлом}
  reset(f);
  i:=0;
  j:=1;
  Write('Пустые строки: ');
  while not eof(f) do    {пока не конец файла}
    begin
      readln(f,s);
      if s='' then 
        begin 
          i:=i+1;
          Write(j,', ');
        end;
      j:=j+1;
    end;
  close(f);
  WriteLn;
  writeln('Количество пустых строк:',i);
  readln;
end.
```

Теперь сравните Ваш код с моим, где понятнее и проще разобраться? Призываю - не пишите сломайглазакод, не для врагов, ведь, пишете.

Comment: ога, код желательно форматировать перед публикацией)

Answer (score 1):

Сделай не через

```
 if eoln(f) then
```

а через

```
 if s = '' then
```

потому, что последняя строка, даже если и не пустая, то будет засчитывать тебе eoln. И с первой строкой ошибки будут.